# How set a view transparent?

Tags: android

I have a class MyView that heritates from View (used to draw on it).
I want to put an image on the background and still be able to draw. Nothing basic works si far
Does any one have a solution?

thanks

```
public class MyView extends View {....}
```

in the main actvity :

```
MyView vueDraw = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.vueDraw);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example that hopefully can get you started.  This is what I do:

```
public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_image);
    }
}
```

Make sure that you're not setting the background color of MyView or any of its sub views (or set them to transparent, which is the default).

EDIT: You may have better luck with this approach (setting the background resource on the window and making sure that MyView's background is transparent:

```
    public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.background_image);
    }
}
```

The TicTacToe example in Android may also prove to be useful.  http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/TicTacToeLib/src/com/example/android/tictactoe/library/GameView.html